# Jenkins: Groovy No signature of method: static hudson.model.Job.getBuildDir()

Tags: jenkins, groovy, continuous-integration, jenkins-workflow

I am using Jenkins 1.6.20 testing the Workflow Plugin which uses Groovy for creating the job as you would know.

I am trying to get information about the current job, for example the working directory of the job.

This is my code:

```
import hudson.EnvVars
import hudson.model.*

def build_number = Job.getBuildDir()

echo "$build_number"
```

It gives me the error:

```
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: static hudson.model.Job.getBuildDir() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
Possible solutions: getBuildDir(), getBuilds(), getBuild(java.lang.String), getBuilds(hudson.model.Fingerprint$RangeSet), getRootDir()
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeStaticMissingMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1367)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeStaticMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1353)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.StaticMetaClassSite.call(StaticMetaClassSite.java:50)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:42)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.DefaultInvoker.methodCall(DefaultInvoker.java:15)
    at WorkflowScript.run(WorkflowScript:4)
    at ___cps.transform___(Native Method)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationGroup.methodCall(ContinuationGroup.java:69)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.dispatchOrArg(FunctionCallBlock.java:106)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.fixName(FunctionCallBlock.java:74)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1418.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationPtr$ContinuationImpl.receive(ContinuationPtr.java:72)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ConstantBlock.eval(ConstantBlock.java:21)
```

Using this documentation:

http://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/hudson/model/Job.html

I can read that the method getBuildDir is actually there and also the error suggest me to use getBuildDir making no sense for me.

Comment: `getBuildDir` is not a static method.  you need an instance of `Job` to call it on, not the class itself

Comment: And how can I get the instance if it has a protected constructor?

Comment: not sure...but you shouldn't need the constructor as there is already a job isnt there?

Comment: The question is not a technicall question about Java Principles, it's about how can I achieve my goal using Jenkins with workflow plugin.

Comment: I was answering your original problem in the question, which was a technical issue about object oriented principles.  I didn't post it as an answer, as I don't know how to do what you want with that jenkins pluigin

Comment: I published my answer  to myself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is useful for someone I could get the workspace dir by:

```
node  {
  def pwdv = pwd()
  echo "path ${pwdv}"
}
```

Comment: Then you do not need the `import`s at all.